# Facebook SDK: Publish scores

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I wan't to publish a score to the graph, but I'm worried that something will be published to the user's timeline. The API mentions that it will automatically generate stories like "User A has beaten your score", but all I really want is for for facebook to hold on to the score for leaderboard purposes.

So my question is, will FB post anything to the user's timeline when a user issues a POST to scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/) then Facebook will on occasion generate stories. Specifically, Facebook will generate stories when a player beats their own previously set high score, and when a player passes the high score of one of their friends.

There is no way to use the Scores API and not have Facebook generate these stories. That said, those stories are very effective ways of reengaging players and bringing new players into your game. I would recommend explaining to players that connecting to Facebook means that their scores may be shared to their timeline and embracing it.